# Occurrences of words using D3 chord diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, diagram, chord-diagram

I want to make a data visualization using chord diagram with D3.js that displays relationships between occurrences of words, i.e. to relate the words that have more occurrences with which less have. Specifically, how should I do the matrix for accomplish that dataviz?

Comment: There are plenty of examples, e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006).

Comment: I want to sort the matrix in another way, because in the example is ordered y grouped as follows:

   [A, B, C, D],
   [B, D, B, F],
   [C, B​​, G, H],
   [D, F, H, I]

Comment: Ok, so order in another way.